# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'educationlevel_api'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

why i receive this error? """ **invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'educationlevel_api'** """ ?? how can i configure this problem??

my Homepage/api/views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def api_detail_educationlevel(request,slug):

  try:
    education = EducationLevel.objects.get(id=slug)
  except EducationLevel.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

  if request.method == "GET":
      serializer = EducationLevelSerializer(education)
      return Response(serializer.data)
```

Homepage/api/serializers.py

```
class EducationLevelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EducationLevel
        field = ('Sequence', 'Description', 'Status')
```

my Homepage/api/urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
         path('<slug>/', api_detail_educationlevel, name="detail"),
    ]
```

my main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('api/educationlevel/', include('Homepage.api.urls', 'educationlevel_api')),
]
```

Comment: Hint: `print(slug)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# specify datatype in your urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:slug>/', api_detail_educationlevel, name="detail"),
]
```

Comment: page not found, how do i call it to my url? "" thisismyurl/api/educationlevel/ "" ?